# erlang binary variable

Tags: binary, erlang

I want to use variable inside <<>> for binary as follows:

```
(emacs@yus-iMac.local)56> Message = "aaa".
"aaa"
(emacs@yus-iMac.local)57> C = <<Message>>.
** exception error: bad argument


(emacs@yus-iMac.local)58> C = <<"aaa">>.
<<"aaa">>
```

First is error, the second is ok. Why? 
Maybe stupid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<<"aaa">>` is syntax sugar for `<<$a,$a,$a>>` there is not any support for direct translating list into binary in bitsyntax.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to use [list_to_binary/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#list_to_binary-1). Like:

```
1> Message = "aaa".
"aaa"
2> C = list_to_binary(Message).
<<"aaa">>
```